# jsp create scripting variable like jsp:usebean does

Tags: jsp, tagfile

I would like to do something like
     `<test:di id="someService"`/`>
    <%
       someService.methodCall();
    %>

where `<test:di`
 gets and instantiates a service bean and creates a scripting variable for use. similar to how jsp:usebean works for example 
    `<jsp:useBean id="someDate" class="java.util.Date"`/>
    <%
       someDate.getYear();

```
%>
```

how do i make my own objects available as a scritping variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way this is done in a Tag Library is by using a Tag Extra Info (TEI) class.

You can find an [example here](http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2001081601&page=2).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to write your own tag library.

Check out the tutorial at:
http://www.ironflare.com/docs/tutorials/taglibs/

Edit:
As Garth pointed out, you want to use the TagExtraInfo class after you've defined your tag lib. 
http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2001081601&page=2

Comment: yup, trying to write my own taglib that sets the "id" attributes to be available as a scripting variable. any ideas?

Comment: Garth Gilmour has the correct answer, i didn't read the question carefully enough. Use the Tag Extra Info class as he recommends.